# Почему приложение не может установиться с play market?

Tags: android, google-play

Приложение в play market в последнее время начило крашится после установки при первом же запуске. В консоли зашкваливает количество сбоев за последние 72 часа. Не получается выявить проблему данных крашей? 
Это ссылка на саму аппу в сторе:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cache.cleaner.booster.ram.storage

Comment: а что надо от нас?

Comment: при чем тут `java`&

Comment: Java при том, что оно разработано на java, в ide android studio

Comment: От вас хочетелось бы услышать, что можно сделать, чтобы прила не крашилась при первом запуске)

Comment: И чисто узнать крашится ли оно на вашем устройстве?)

Comment: для этого скачайте nox, b запускайте

Comment: никто скачивать за вас не будет)

Comment: А как тогда мне узнать в чем проблема, если оно крашится только при скачивании из маркета?)

Comment: у вас, при запуске из студии, работает?

Comment: Нет, в том и дело, что из студи  все работает прекрасно, но когда я его запускаю из маркета, то при самом первом запуске оно вылетает

Comment: попробуйте в студии используйте эмулятор именно то устройство, где у вас крашится

Comment: если уж и это не поможет, то не знаю....

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую!)